# Tinymce - have a menubar item as a toolbar item

Tags: editor, tinymce-4

I am using tinymce editor, and have an edit menubar item, which I would like to move into toolbar, I have tried with just adding it to toolbar, but that doesn't work obviously:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#content',
    paste_data_images: true,
    menubar: 'edit',
    statusbar: false,
    height: 500,
    theme: 'modern',
    plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
        'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
        'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
        'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'
    ],
    toolbar1: 'bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link | paste',
```

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly state menus and toolbars are different so you cannot just throw a menu option (`edit`) in a toolbar - that will not work.

The `Edit` menu contains several options:

```
Undo, Redo, Cut, Copy, Paste, etc...
```

Look through the TinyMCE documentation for toolbar control identifiers and you will find that most (if not all) of the commands have a toolbar equivalent:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/editor-control-identifiers/#toolbarcontrols

You need to add these control identifiers to the toolbar in TinyMCE.